# Loading local HTML into UIWebView on iOS not showing local images or styling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm having an issue getting local images and css stylesheet to show through on a local HTML page using UIWebView on an iPad app that will be using iOS 5.

The HTML page itself shows through and is laid out well, which is great. But the problem is it has blank squares where images should be coming through, and styling on text or anywhere isn't showing either.

I've come across very similar questions on SO where people have said to load the HTML into the view with the baseURL, which I then did using an answer from their question. But the images and style still did not come through.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:@"html_files"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[web loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

The UIWebView is put in place using Interface Builder and I have that in the .h file as `@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *web;`

Inside my `html_files` folder I have:

- index.htm
- img (folder)
- style (folder)

Using the following code, the log showed `"index.htm", img, style` which tells me it's keeping the directories the same, but I still even tried placing and then linking to images in the root of `html_files` but still nothing.

```
NSString *htmlPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"html_files"];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:htmlPath];
NSLog(@"%@", dirContents);
```

And then within index.htm I'm linking to images like `<img src="img/logo.jpg">`

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Added link to project here: http://www.filedropper.com/localhtml (it's literally just a UIWebView with the HTML files so nothing big and messy)

Comment: On that one page I have 5 different images, and in the img folder I have 9 images.

Comment: for img tag, r u using the exact image name from the bundle..? like imageName.jpg

Comment: Yes, I am using bundle image name. I've uploaded the project (it's currently just a UIWebView and the HTML files) to http://www.filedropper.com/localhtml if you'd kindly like to take a look yourself, maybe you can see something I cannot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here a re the mistakes you made, i said just use only image name in the img tag, you where using the path.

In iOS not mater how many folders you have, where ever you have the resources, it just adds all the resources in a single bundle.

[image: Sample screen shot after changes]

Here is the [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/Local%20HTML.zip), check out i have made the changes only in index.htm

Comment: Thanks very much vishy. The NSLog of the html_files directory confused me a bit as it still showed the folder structure. Thanks a lot for your help, and the link. Please feel free to leave the link and image up, hopefully will help someone else out in the future. Thanks again!